# Unity IAP для IOS

Tags: ios, unity3d, appstore

Пришлось столкнуться с такой проблемой:

У меня приложение с полностью рабочими встроенными покупками под андроид на основе unity iap.

**Вопрос:** Как переделать(проблема может быть в коде(!!! может ли быть) или нужно плагины скачать другие под ios?) 
чтобы работали покупки в апсторе(они уже зареганы)

PS первый раз выпускаю приложение под ios,не пойму специфику апстора никак